# Emacs 24.2 CUA-mode behaviour on Shift-up/down

Tags: emacs, cua-mode, cua

I've set `(cua-mode t)` in my ~/.emacs in GNU Emacs 24.2 on Windows XP. However, when (with nothing selected) I type shift-up or shift-down no new selection is started, which is not the CUA behaviour as seen in MS Notepad, Eclipse etc. If I type shift-left/right then shift-up/down then indeed a new selection is created and extended as I continue to type shift-up/down.

Now, in Emacs 23.1 the initialisation sequence:
`(pc-selection-mode)
(load "cua-mode")
(CUA-mode t)`
did exhibit the expected behaviour, but all that is now obsolete AFAICS. So, any ideas on how to get the initial shift-selection working as in other Windows apps?

Comment: What happens when you start it like `emacs -q` and do nothing but try to select some text with shift-movement?  What happens after you enable `cua-mode`?  Shift selection works for me in both cases.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me the clue to what was happening as it worked OK in `-q` mode. Then running `C-h k` showed that the up/down keys had been globally rebound to non-standard operations in an obscure part of my `~/.emacs`. Problem solved :)